# onActivityResult() is never call in nested Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-tabhost

I have the next UI hierarhy:

`FragmentActivity` -> `Fragment` with `TabHost` and LocalActivityManager -> MyNestedActivity

MyNestedActivity places in single tab in `Fragment`. When I call `startActivityForResult()` in MyNestedActivity, `Activity` starts normally, but `onActivityResult()` in never called.

But if I open MyNestedActivity using `startActivity()`, `onActivityResult()` works fine.

When I must hook `onActivityResult()`? In `FragmentActivity` on in `Fragment`? How I must dispatch result to my MyNestedActivity?

SOLVED:

In this UI hierarhy `onActivityResult()` not called. I just change MyNestedActivity to `Fragment` and my hierarchy become `FragmentActivity` -> `Fragment`. Now `onActivityResult()` works fine.

Comment: i guess your onActivityresult is being taken by your parent activity just see by taking logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onActivityResult()` in nested `Activity` not call by Android.

The correct way to get activity result in nested activity is:

1. `startActivityForResult()` from host `Activity` (not from nested!),
2. receive `Activity` result in host `Activity`,
3. dispatch `Activity` result to nested `Activity`.

Comment: Hi @Flexo , How can we dispatch activity result to nested activities?

Comment: @heyjii, call startActivity from your parent activity and receive result in parent activity. Then pass result to nested activity.

Comment: This is a very good idea - untangling nested calls by redispatching thorugh top level.  I've just run into trouble with nested intents - when you use startActivityForResult and "return" an intent to the parent, nested returns sometimes lose the intent.  Upvote for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `startActivityForResult()` from a Fragment you have to set the `onActivityResult()` method in the Fragment class and not in the host Activity. See [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) for more informations.

Comment: Ok, I may have misunderstood your problem. Sorry.But this worked for me with the following UI hierarhy : Activity hosting a Fragment.

Comment: Yes, it work if activity hosts a fragment, but it not work if fragment hosts activity!

Answer (score 0):

We had this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/65oLmvIlgFM problem and solvedit by changing the activities launchMode to something other that singleInstace or singleTask.